# Nesting state in react to reduce amount of props being passed

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a large component that needs 10 different values in `state`.

I can split it into smaller components to improve readability albeit I don't except to reuse any of those components anywhere else -- they are still too specific as they need to know too much about the state to be useful.

Because of this, I'm passing at least 6 different props to each of child component. So while I'm improving readability by making components smaller, I, at the same time, make readability worse by passing too many props each child components.

So I was thinking of different approaches how to solve this.

1.

Group state into a single value to move it around easier

E.g. instead of

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

store it as

```
{
  abc: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  }
}
```

And then pass to child components as a single prop.

2.

Since my child components are stateless, just pass state as `<Child {...this.state} />`.

3. Use redux and pass `store`, however, I might be wrong but I think, relying on `store.getState` would turn my simple child components into containers (in redux terms).

Apologies if this question is too generic.

Comment: Using the destructor on your state the way you showed in 2 is fine, I think.

Comment: You can also combine approaches 1 and 3 , splitting your state in a redux store and connect only the parent component (the container), then pass some datas by props to the children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 works if you want to stick to using the component's state vs Redux.

Personally, I would use Redux and map state to props on the most parent component, making that the only container. Then you could destructure the prop value down to the child components:

```
<Child {...this.props.exampleProp} />
```